# Compare two cells with different values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

So I have two columns:

1. Values can be "Yes - Start", "Yes - End", "Yes - Both" and "No"
2. Values are the same as column 1

They don't match all the time, so I want to create an additional column that would say:

- "Rare", if cell in column 2 is different from "No"
- "Common", if cell in column 2 is equal to "No"
- "C&R", if cells from both columns (A1 and B1, for e.g.) have a value different from "No"

I tried

```
=IF(B1="No";"Common";"Rare")
```

But this only solves the first two points, the "C&R" one I don't know how to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've understood this right, then you could use the following formula:

```
=IF(B1="No","Common",IF(AND(A1<>"No",B1<>"No"),"C&R","Rare"))
```

It basically breaks down to:

- If B1 is no then it's *Common*
- If B1 is one of the yes values then it's *C&R* if **both** A1 and B1 are yes values, otherwise B1 is *Rare*.

For your additional requirement in the comments of returning "None" if both A1 and B1 are no then change the formula to:

```
=IF(B1="No",(IF(A1="No","None","Common")),IF(AND(A1<>"No",B1<>"No"),"C&R","Rare"))
```

This breaks down to:

- If B1 is no then it's *Common* if A1 is one of the yes values, otherwise it's *None*
- If B1 is one of the yes values then it's *C&R* if **both** A1 and B1 are yes values, otherwise B1 is *Rare*.

Comment: Thanks! This does it, although I noticed something now.. when both A1 and B1 are "no", the result should be "None", or else it will look odd. How can I do that? Also, what do <> mean? Thank again for your time!

Comment: @Santiago <> means "not equal to". I'll edit my answer in a second to add in your latest requirement.

Comment: thanks you so much! this does it! I'll study the formula well so next time I'll be good on my own.

Answer (score 1):

this should do it:

```
=IF(AND(A1<>"No",B1<>"No"), "C&R",IF(B1="No", "Common", "Rare"))
```

This basically says -

```
if both columns aren't "No", then "C&R" // your last case
else 
  if second column is "No", then "Common" // your 2nd case
  else "Rare" // i.e., it's not "No"   // your first case
```